# Hibernate Mapping to field in Collection of same entities

Tags: hibernate, hibernate-mapping

i have an issue in hibernate mapping. I have the below hibernate entities A,B and the mapping file which is getting the data from VIEW.

```
public entity A {
 private B b;
 ..
}
public entity B {
  private String fieldToMap;
  private List<B> list;
}
```

Below is my view mapping file

```
<class name = "A">
  <subselect> select ... from VIEW</subselect>

   <!-- TODO need to map  -->

</class>
```

The problem is i need to map A == > List ==> **fieldToMap** to a particular column in the view. So can any one help me with the mapping code in the TODO place ? Is this possible ?

I tried something like below but didnt work

```
<class name = "A">
  <subselect> select ... from VIEW</subselect> 
    <component name = "b">
     <bag name ="list" lazy="false" cascade = "all">
      ....
    </bag>
   </component>
</class>
```

Comment: Please post your schema as it is not clear what you are asking.

Comment: I just have a view which is drawn from multiple tables.. But in the mapping we are just referring to only View ...

Comment: So the view contains the data for all the B's? Or Do you want to gather multiple lines from the view to one A and multiple Bs (one B per line)?